# count the number of taxonomies in script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that says if there are checkboxes with the value greater than 63, than show div, otherwise hide div.

```
function show_no_taxonomies() {
 if ($('.store_checkbox:checked').val() > 63){
    $("#hidden_taxon_message").show();
    $("#hidden_taxon_message").text('This store does not have any texonomies');
 }else {
    $("#hidden_taxon_message").hide(); // something is selected
   }
}
```

I need to redefine this conditional if statement to count the taxonomies. I have this tag attached to all of these checkboxes :

```
taxonomies_count="0"
```

I need the conditional statement to say  if there are checkboxes with the **taxonomies_count** greater than 0, than show div, otherwise hide div.

```
<input id="idea_store_ids_" class="store_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="124"   
taxonomies_count="0" name="idea[store_ids][]"></input>
```

Comment: Show us the markup for one of the checkboxes so we can see what you mean :)

Comment: mark up added to original

Comment: Is this in addition to the val check, or instead of?

Comment: instead of the val check

Comment: Consider using the slightly more standard-compliant `data-` attribute notation, so that `taxonomies_count` becomes `data-taxonomies-count`. Then you can use `$(this).data("taxonomies-count")` to get the value, and it will be an number already.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you've asked...

```
function show_no_taxonomies() {
    var taxonomiesCount = false;
    $('.store_checkbox:checked').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("taxonomies_count") > 0) {
            taxonomiesCount = true;
            return;
        }
    });
    if (!taxonomiesCount){
        $("#hidden_taxon_message").show();
        $("#hidden_taxon_message").text('This store does not have any taxonomies');
    }else {
        $("#hidden_taxon_message").hide(); // something is selected
    }
}
```

However, I'd recommend using a data attribute, rather than a custom attribute.  Like this...

```
<input id="idea_store_ids_" class="store_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="124" data-taxonomies-count="0" name="idea[store_ids][]" />
```

and the script would be...

```
function show_no_taxonomies() {
    var taxonomiesCount = false;
    $('.store_checkbox:checked').each(function() {
        if ($(this).data("taxonomies-count") > 0) {
            taxonomiesCount = true;
            return;
        }
    });
    if (!taxonomiesCount){
        $("#hidden_taxon_message").show();
        $("#hidden_taxon_message").text('This store does not have any taxonomies');
    }else {
        $("#hidden_taxon_message").hide(); // something is selected
    }
}
```

Comment: the message does not appear and disappear

Comment: LOL - my bad.  Try it now.  I'm not used to typing the word "taxonomies" so I spelt it 2 different ways :p

Comment: Arg- Now it wont appear when I click a checkbox

Comment: Have you assigned the click event handler to the checkbox correctly?  Open the console in your browser and enter `show_no_taxonomies()` to run the function manually.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by logically simplifying my code by making 2 more large picture functions. Then, calling those functions into my larger function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".store_checkbox").change(function () {
    $('div[store_id=' + this.value + ']').toggle(this.checked);
    show_no_store_message();
}).change();
show_no_store_message();
});

function show_no_store_message() {
if (!is_store_selected()) {
    $("#hidden_taxon_message").show(); // none are checked
    $("#hidden_taxon_message").text('Please select store before selecting taxonomies');
} else if (is_store_selected()  && !do_any_stores_have_taxonomies() ) {
    $("#hidden_taxon_message").show(); // none are checked
    $("#hidden_taxon_message").text('None of the stores you selected have taxonomies');

} else {
    $("#hidden_taxon_message").hide(); // something is selected
}
}

// returns true if any store is selected
function is_store_selected(){
return ($('.store_checkbox:checked').length > 0);
}

// Returns true if any store selected AND store has taxonomiess
function do_any_stores_have_taxonomies(){
$('.store_checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("taxonomies_count") > 0) {
     return true;   
    }
});
return false;
}
```